# Old Git server is not working, try to migrate all the repositories to a new server

Tags: git, ubuntu, nginx, gitlab, migrate

I have a bunch of Git repositories in the old server where the server is not able to start the Gitlab service (Unicorn Web Server is not able to start). I have setup a new server and move some of the repositories over. But I have a problem on moving those are not cloned in my local machine. Is there a way I can migrate all the repositories manually in ubuntu by copying all the files in the Repositories folder?

Below are some of my setup in the old/new server:

**Old Server**

Ubuntu 12.04

Gitlab (not sure what version as it is pretty old, not using Omnibus)

**New Server**

Ubuntu 16.04

Gitlab 8.1 (Omnibus, default settings)

Situation:

1) I am not able to start the Unicorn Web Server which means I am not able to clone the repo

2) Not able to access to the web also

3) I am able to go to the Gitlab folder and edit/copy files from there

4) I tried fixing the Unicorn Web Server issue but no luck on it after 2 days of googling, I have decided to move to a complete new server by setting up the Gitlab from scratch using Omnibus (able to move around 40 repos over, 80 repos left in the old server)

5) The error started after I upgrade the Ubuntu from 11.10 to 12.04. Gitlab/Nginx config are still using the old version which it should be working since I did not update the Gitlab

Below are are the errors I got from unicorn.stderr.log

```
I, [2016-10-11T16:48:16.274983 #19725]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
NameError: uninitialized constant Sprockets::Rails
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.7/lib/bootstrap-sass/engine.rb:11:in `block in <class:Engine>'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.2.22.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.2.22.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.2.22.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.2.22.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.2.22.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.2.22.5/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.2.22.5/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
  /home/git/gitlab/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
  config.ru:4:in `require'
  config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
  config.ru:1:in `new'
  config.ru:1:in `<main>'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/lib/unicorn.rb:48:in `eval'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/lib/unicorn.rb:48:in `block in builder'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/bin/unicorn_rails:139:in `block in rails_builder'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:722:in `build_app!'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:140:in `start'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/bin/unicorn_rails:209:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/local/bin/unicorn_rails:23:in `load'
  /usr/local/bin/unicorn_rails:23:in `<top (required)>'
```

Comment: Out of complete and utter curiosity what is the error that you're getting when you're trying to start unicorn?

Easiest way to migrate your GitLab server would be to backup all the repositories locally as well as your GitLab configuration folder. And upload it to the new one or alternatively grabbing the database as well and reconstructing the old server configuration for an upgrade.

Comment: I have updated the error from the log file